# Android: Presist the UI State and Data in Android(Kotlin)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments

I have A Bottom Navigation Bar Using Navigation Components It Contain 3 Fragments let Say A(Home), B And C. When I Moved From B To C Fragment B Destroys And Similarly C To B C Destroys. When I Re-Select A It Again Makes Network Call Fetches The Data and Display. I Don't Want To Make A Network Request Again And Again When Fragment Destroys Or Re-Selected.

I'm Using ViewModel, Retrofit, LiveData, Coroutines And Kotlin.

Please Help Me To Fix This Problem

### Base Fragment

```
abstract class BaseFragment<VM: ViewModel, VB: ViewBinding, R: BaseRepository>:Fragment() {

private var _viewBinding: VB? = null
protected val viewBinding
     get() = _viewBinding!!

protected lateinit var viewModel: VM

protected lateinit var userTokenData: UserTokenData

protected lateinit var remoteDataStore: RemoteDataSource

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    remoteDataStore = RemoteDataSource()

    userTokenData = UserTokenData(requireContext())

    _viewBinding = getFragmentBinding(inflater, container)

    val factory = ViewModelFactory(getRepository())

    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(getViewModelClass())

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        userTokenData.token.first()
    }

    return viewBinding.root
}
abstract fun getViewModelClass():Class<VM>

abstract fun getFragmentBinding(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?): VB

abstract fun getRepository(): R

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    Log.d(MyTAG, "onDestroyView")
    _viewBinding = null
}
```

### Home Fragment

```
class HomeFragment : BaseFragment<HomeViewModel, FragmentHomeBinding, UserRepository>() {

override fun getViewModelClass() = HomeViewModel::class.java

override fun getFragmentBinding(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?
) = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

override fun getRepository(): UserRepository {
    val token = runBlocking { userTokenData.token.first() }
   return UserRepository(remoteDataStore.buildApi(UserApi::class.java, token))
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    viewBinding.progressBar.visible(true)

    viewModel.user.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

        when(it){
            is Resources.Success -> {
                updateUI(it.value.user)
            }


            is Resources.Loading -> {
                viewBinding.progressBar.visible(true)
            }
        }
    })
}

fun updateUI(user: User){
    viewBinding.progressBar.visible(false)
    viewBinding.email.text = user.email
    viewBinding.name.text = user.name
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In each Fragment, put this before `onCreate`

```
private val myViewModel: MyViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

Also, in order to do that, you will need to have this dependency:

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5"
```

Comment: I don't use separate fragment for each fragment and I'm using base fragment and extending it

Comment: @john It should work either way. Try using `by activityViewModels()` and I believe you will achieve what you're looking for

Comment: didn't work. can i initialize it or leave it just adding or some other stuff. Please explain briefly and help me

Comment: It's working fine fine but when i need to pass parameter to viewodel it throws runtime error cannot create instance of class viewmodel. Help me